# boost::shared_ptr<> "explicit shared_ptr( Y * p ): px( p ), pn() // Y must be complete"

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, polymorphism, shared-ptr

Can someone help me with the following error I get when trying to return an object polymorphically within a boost::smart_ptr:

```
1>C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_54_0\boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp(352): error : a value of type "PBO *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "O*"

1>        explicit shared_ptr( Y * p ): px( p ), pn() // Y must be complete
```

this is the code and the first method is where the error occurs. **Is it because i'm missing a copy constructor or assignment operator and boost::shared_ptr requires those to be defined, hence "complete"??**

CE.cpp

```
#include "CE.h"

boost::shared_ptr<OB> CE::getObject(){
                                //THIS IS WHERE THE ABOVE ERROR OCCURS
    return boost::shared_ptr<OB>(new PBO);
}
```

CE.h

```
#include "E.h"
#include "PBO.h"

#include <boost\shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>

class CE: public E{

public:

    virtual boost::shared_ptr<OB> getObject();

private:

};
```

E.h

```
#include "OB.h"

#include <boost\shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>

class E{

public:

    virtual boost::shared_ptr<OB> getObject() = 0;

private:

};
```

OB.h

```
//The parent class in the polymorphic hierarchy:
class OB{
public:

    OB();
    virtual void c(boost::shared_ptr<OD> lo);
    virtual void d(std::unordered_map<double, long> a, std::set<double> b, boost::shared_ptr<OD> o) = 0;

protected:

};
```

PBO.h

```
#include "OD.h"
#include "OB.h"

//The child class in the polymorphic hierarchy:
class PBO : public OB{

public:
    PBO();
    virtual void c(boost::shared_ptr<OD> l);

private:
    virtual void d(std::unordered_map<double, long> a, std::set<double> b, boost::shared_ptr<OD> c);

};
```

Comment: it need header file/full definition of the class

Comment: "Complete" means that the type definition (not just declaration) must be seen at that point. Is `PBO` definition is seen there?

Comment: I get this error for OB: "error : not a class or struct name" I presume this error could be causing the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to error function `boost::shared_ptr<OB> CE::getObject()` only sees `class PBO` forward declaration, not definition. But as it has to convert `PBO *` to it's base `OB *` it has to see definition of the class PBO. Solution could be to put function declaration into header:

```
class OB; // if you put this function declaration before definition of class OB
boost::shared_ptr<OB> getObject();
```

and implementation into cpp file, where both definition of `OB` and `PBO` are visible:

```
#include "OB.h"
#include "PBO.h"

boost::shared_ptr<OB> CE::getObject(){
   return boost::shared_ptr<OB>(new PBO);
}
```

Comment: I have added OB.h and PBO.h to the CE.h header and it still makes no difference :s

Comment: In your question you do not specify which file is which so it is difficult to diagnose why.

Comment: Ok have added all the classes with labels now- hope that helps?

Comment: File PBO.h is not included into CE.cpp not directly not indirectly through CE.h. What do you expect?

Comment: I added it, then ran the code, then removed it before copying. Let me insert it back, re-run and confirm it still doesnt work. I'll edit the code above to include them once I have modified it.

Comment: Added it but made no difference

Comment: If you send me your email address (somehow) I will email you the code in full. Its a Visual Studio project- way too much to try and put on SO.

Comment: You have to use header guards or pragma once, otherwise you would get error as OB.h included twice. I bet you use the same guards for different header files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41668/discussion-between-user997112-and-slava)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use chat. Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard and check if you use different guards for different headers.